# How to Install Cloudflare warp cli in ubuntu 23.04 or any non LTS versions?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, cloudflare

I'm trying to install Cloudflare Warp on my Ubuntu 23.04, but it seems that the official Cloudflare repository only provides support for LTS versions. Consequently, I'm unable to find a straightforward method to install Cloudflare Warp on my system.

I couldn't find any specific instructions for non-LTS versions. Can someone guide me on how to install Cloudflare Warp on Ubuntu 23.04 (or any other non-LTS version) using an alternative method?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The official instructions from https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/#ubuntu has one small issue that needs to be fixed to install Warp on Ubuntu 23.04.**

Use the following three commands. *(Note that I changed `$(lsb_release -cs)` to `bookworm` in the second command and that is the only change required for Ubuntu 23.04)*

### Commands:

```
# Add cloudflare gpg key
curl https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/pubkey.gpg | sudo gpg --yes --dearmor --output /usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-warp-archive-keyring.gpg


# Add this repo to your apt repositories
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-warp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/ bookworm main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-client.list


# Install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cloudflare-warp
```

### Explanation:

If you type `lsb_release -cs` into your terminal in Ubuntu 23.04 it will return:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Codename:   lunar
```

Instead try the command `cat /etc/debian_version` which returns:

```
bookworm/sid
```

So the replacement command above becomes the following (you drop the "/sid" portion):

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-warp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/ bookworm main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-client.list
```

After the install a `warp-cli register` and a `warp-cli connect` should get you up and running. You should see a cloud icon in your tray and of course verify with 1.1.1.1/help to make sure that "Using DNS over WARP" is "Yes" and your IPv4 and IPv6 resolvers aren't your ISP's.

Hope that helps!